# Anonymous classes and interfaces

Tags: java, swing, oop, interface, anonymous-class

I will illustrate my issue with the use of an example:

The addActionListener method accepts an ActionListener Interface as its only argument.

So when invoking that method on an object/component (such as a Button) in order to register a listener to the object, through the use of an anonymous inner class, why is it that we also need to implement the Interface class? Is it because by definition, interfaces cannot be instantiated, unless of course you are creating an object of that Interface type that implements the abstract methods of that Interface?

i.e.

```
aButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

That is, through the use of anonymous classes, we can **avoid explicitly** making the entire class implementing the interface (as declared in the header), but rather we are instantiating an object of the Interface (which by definition of an Interface shouldn't be possible) and implementing the Interface's abstract methods within the anonymous class.

So it is only possible to instantiate an object the Interface due to the fact that at that point in time, a contract needs to be fulfilled to implement the Interface's methods, and in doing so, allows us to make an object from the Interface?

Therefore, is the reason why we can implement the actionPerformed() method of the Interface only possible because of the fact that we had instantiated an object from the Interface (which simultaneously requires us to fulfil the contract of implementing the abstract methods)? So could it be said that we are '**implicitly**' implementing an interface by the **in-situ instantiation** of the Interface (as the addActionListener argument)?

Comment: I think you're overthinking it.  You are defining a concrete class that implements the interface, and instantiating an object of that concrete class.  Just the same as if you had a named class that implements the interface, except without giving the class a name.  I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: An Interface can be seen as a contract that defines a set functions that any implementing classes are guaranteed to provide. `addActionListener` is saying "I need something that can do `ActionListener` stuff"

Answer (score 3):

You are not instantiating the interface.

You are defining and instantiating an actual, concrete class that implements the interface.  You need to implement every method declared in the interface, just as if you wrote a "normal" class implementing the interface.

The anonymous class construct saves you the trouble of having to name a class that is only going to be used in one very specific place in your code.  But if you wanted to you could have decided to do that.  Under the covers it is the same thing -- you have defined a class to implement the interface and then instantiated that class.